# Как и почему выбрано правило сокращений букв?

Tags: сокращения, правила

Вопросов по теме сокращений **много**, в том числе их много **на нашем форуме**: отвечающие уверенно приводят нужное **правило.** Безусловно, мы должны писать по единому образцу.

Но никто не задал вопрос: почему принято **именно такое правило?** Почему мы  охотно расстаемся с гласными буквами, но так бережем все согласные, стоящие перед гласной.

Вероятно, этот принцип имеет обоснование, а какое?

**ПРАВИЛА РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ И ПУНКТУАЦИИ (1956 Г.)**

*При стечении двух различных или нескольких согласных сокращение следует делать **после последней согласной**, например: народн. творчество (а не «народ.»), русск. язык (а не «рус.»), искусств. шелк (а не «искус.», или «искусс.», или «искусст.»).*