# Другое правило о наращении окончаний порядковых числительных (второй вариант, с обоснованием)

Tags: стилистика, сокращения, правила

Можно ли составить короткое  правило о наращении окончаний  порядковых числительных  с использованием **согласных и гласных букв.**

Answer (score 3):

Это  другое правило с использованием **согласных и гласных букв**. Также приведено объяснение **смысла** этого правила (как я его понимаю).

**ПРАВИЛО**

(1) **Наращение** порядковых числительных может быть однобуквенным или двухбуквенным.

(2) Чаще используется **однобуквенное** наращение. Это последняя   буква в порядковом числительном: **согласная** или йотированная гласная Ю, Я, Е, например:

**3-й** класс,  в **1-м** классе, в **3-м** классе, с **3-м** классом, **3-я** четверть, **3-ю** четверть, **3-е** полугодие.

Этих букв достаточно для обозначения формы порядкового числительного.

(3) **Двухбуквенное** наращение используется редко: это сочетание гласной и согласной букв ***-ГО, -МУ***, например: из **3-го** класса,  к **3-му** классу.

Отдельные гласные  ***О*** и ***У*** недостаточно информативны для обозначения формы слова.

**ОБОСНОВАНИЕ**:

(1) Можно предположить, что **согласные** буквы более **информативны** при передаче семантики слова, поэтому **предыдущую** гласную можно не писать, в то время как  отдельная **согласная** может обозначить форму порядкового числительного.

(2) **Йотированные** гласные также могут быть однобуквенным наращением, так как они обозначают **сочетание** согласного и гласного звуков.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**Первое правило в теме** [Как коротко записать правило о наращении падежного окончания порядковых числительных?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475419/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB)

**Смежная тема** [Как и почему выбрано правило сокращений букв?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475398/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2)

Из комментария по теме **для участника @Александр Стрелец**

*Согласные **важнее** гласных (никто эту тему не захотел мне, к сожалению,  объяснить, а я так рассчитывала). В древней письменности Египта ведь не было гласных dzen.ru/a/Xep6TeMGLACutoKv Да и нашу речь возьмите, в послеударных позициях слышится пара неопределенных гласных (мягкая и твердая). Вот поэтому и важнее. И мне не жаль потерянного времени, так как я сама стла лучше понимать это правило. И большое спасибо за помощь, **без вас бы я не справилась**))*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148980/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец если есть какие-то вопросы по модерации, можно задать их на https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @МаркИз Спасибо, Мета вообще не действует. Короче, модерация оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: @МаркИз  О! Так вы вообще сейчас удалили восстановленные вами комментарии?! Прекрасно... Вы так и не ответили, почему 10 комментариев ушли в чат, а 20 и более часто не уходят.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец вопросы модерации и функционирования сайта можно обсудить на Мете. Здесь к моменту появления чата было под 30 комментариев флуда, то что большую часть вы уже удалили этого не меняет.

Comment: Я удалила только одно сообщение о чате. Александр сказал,чо он случайно нажал не ту кнопку (про приглашение в чат).   У меня не получалось выбрать правильную запись, и Александр указывал мне на ошибки. (Флуд — малосодержательные и нетематические сообщения в интернет-форумах и чатах, зачастую занимающие большие объёмы.)  Я всегда соглашаюсь с действиями модераторов, но в этой теме    мне тоже непонятен перенос в чат.

Comment: @Sharon вы удалили 6 комментариев, Александр - 8

Comment: Вы самые первые имеете в виду? Там было не обсуждение чернового варианта правила, а прямое указание на неточности, и Александр предупредил меня, что удалит свои комментарии. Зачем лишний информационный шум.