# В каком предложении НЕ со словом пишется раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, части-речи

1. Наступила осень с **(не)скончаемыми** дождями, мокрыми дорогами, с тоской по вечерам.
2. Док в месте переправы далеко **(не)широкий**, всего около сорока метров.
3. Где-то здесь, в нескольких шагах, раздавались **(не)забываемые** трели соловья, и тишина наполнилась дивными звуками.

Во 2-м предложении частица НЕ пишется слитно: в сочетании с прилагательным, она образует слово противоположного значения и не подразумевается противопоставления.

А вот с 1-м и 3-м предложением не совсем понятно. Мне кажется, что НЕСКОНЧАЕМЫЕ пишется слитно: это причастие без зависимых слов.

В 3-м предложении не могу определить часть речи. НЕ ЗАБЫВАЕМЫЕ - это причастие? Если да, то оно распространенное - "трели (кого?) соловья".

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

Comment: С наращениями надо разобраться.  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475473/%d0%94%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81

Comment: Кажется, исправил. Спасибо за замечание!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Раздельное** написание НЕ с прилагательным: *Док в месте переправы **далеко не широкий**, всего около сорока метров.*  Усиление отрицания: ***далеко не.***
2. **Слитное** написание НЕ: *Наступила осень с **нескончаемыми** дождями, мокрыми дорогами, с тоской по вечерам. Где-то здесь, в нескольких шагах, раздавались **незабываемые** трели соловья, и тишина наполнилась дивными звуками.*

Это **прилагательные** (качественный признак), зависимые слова не влияют на запись НЕ.

**НЕСКОНЧАЕМЫЙ**. Чрезвычайно длинный или длительный; бесконечный (во времени и в пространстве). Н. путь. Н-ые леса. Войска шли нескончаемым потоком. Н-ая ночь, зима. Н. разговор. Н-ая беседа.

**НЕЗАБЫВАЕМЫЙ,** -ая, -ое; -ваем, -а, -о. Такой, о котором нельзя забыть; памятный. Н-ые дни юности. Н. подвиг. Н-ое горе. Н-ая дата. Н. спектакль. Н. по красоте пейзаж. <Незабываемость, -и; ж. Н. горя, обиды, утраты.

**ТЕОРИЯ**

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77)** **§ 57. Частица не с прилагательными (п.13 и п.14).**

1. Написание НЕ со словами на -мый регулируется **особыми правилами**.
2. Большинство слов является **прилагательными** со слитным написанием. **Исключение:** усиление отрицания, реже противопоставление. Но надо учитывать те случаи, когда слово **без НЕ** не используется.
3. Раздельно пишутся **причастия**, образованные от **переходных** глаголов **несовершенного** вида **при наличии** в предложении **слова в Т. п.** (субъект или инструмент действия).

Только тогда **значение действия** будет проявлено в должной мере (как происходящее в **текущий** момент), например: ***не видимый мною** предмет.*

Comment: Возник еще 1 пример. Подскажите, пожалуйста.*Не кончающийся от соседа шум и гам продолжался до вечера.* будет раздельно? Спасибо!

Comment: Шум не кончается от соседей – неверное управление.  Надо проверять по словарю http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=кончиться  Дополнение только  в Т.п.  Не кончается (чем?).  Не получится подобрать вариант зависимого слова с нужным значением, как я думаю. Поэтому используем прилагательное.